# Prometheus not showing flink metrics

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

I have following code in my flink job;

```
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
          this.counter = getRuntimeContext()
                        .getMetricGroup()
                        .counter("myCounter");
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, String> map(String s) throws Exception {
            this.counter.inc();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(s, s.toUpperCase());
    }
```

In prometheus.yml inside prometheus distribution, I have following:

```
- job_name: 'flink-prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9999']
    metrics_path: /
```

And in flink-conf.yaml inside flink distribution:

```
metrics.reporters: prom
  metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
  metrics.reporter.prom.host: 127.0.0.1
  metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9999
```

On prometheus board, I can see localhost:9999 as target, and also various metric logs. But there is no log for the counter I have added in the code. I searched for  string "myCounter" as well as "flink-prometheus", but zero results.

What else I need to do for my metrics to show up?

Comment: Hopefully this complete example -- https://github.com/mbode/flink-prometheus-example -- will help.

Comment: I followed that repository for my implementation, and don't think I missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference I see between the example in https://github.com/mbode/flink-prometheus-example and your own config is that the example is scraping the job manager as well as the task manager(s):

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'flink'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['job-cluster:9249', 'taskmanager1:9249', 'taskmanager2:9249']
```

In my own example -- see [Flink Timing Explorer](https://github.com/alpinegizmo/timing-explorer) -- I found it necessary to do this as well. Here's what worked for me:

flink-conf.yaml

```yaml
metrics.reporters: prom
metrics.reporter.prom.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9250-9260
```

prometheus.yaml

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  evaluation_interval: 5s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'flink'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:9250', 'host.docker.internal:9251']
```

Comment: So I changed to 'metrics.reporter.prom.port: 9250-9260' in flink-conf.yml and 'targets: ['localhost:9250','localhost:9251', 'localhost:9999']' in prometheus.yaml. But I still don't see any custom metrics on prometheus. These files are in their respective application installation folders(in sample applications they are included jut for reference, I assume).

Comment: I also observed that prometheus dashboard shows localhost:9250 as UP while other 2 addresses as DOWN.

Comment: I don't remember why, but I also set `jobmanager.rpc.address: localhost` in flink-conf.yaml.